# tinyxml2 building and writing xml file on c++

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

I am trying to build a simple xml file using tinyxml2 in VS2019,
for some reason the code works until it hits the element named port.
this element and every element after it is ignored in the xml file.
I just noticed, it is also writing xml output in the wrong order, host should be the one right below , not port.

What am i missing here?

Truth be told, i have about 2 days experience writing c++, and very basic python knowlage.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include "tinyxml/tinyxml2.h"

using namespace tinyxml2;
using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

    char* appdata;
    size_t len;
    errno_t err = _dupenv_s(&appdata, &len, "APPDATA");

    fs::path path = appdata;
    path /= "FileZilla";
    path /= "sitemanager.xml";

    TCHAR username[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
    GetUserName((TCHAR*)username, &size);

    tinyxml2::XMLDocument xmlDoc;

    //tinyxml2::XMLDeclaration* decl = new XMLDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "");


    XMLElement* pRoot = xmlDoc.NewElement("FileZilla3");
    pRoot->SetAttribute("Version", "");
    pRoot->SetAttribute("Platform", "");
    xmlDoc.InsertFirstChild(pRoot);

    XMLElement* child = xmlDoc.NewElement("Servers");
    child->SetText("\n");
    pRoot->InsertEndChild(child);

    XMLElement* subchild = xmlDoc.NewElement("Server");
    subchild->SetText("\n");
    child->InsertEndChild(subchild);

    XMLElement* host = xmlDoc.NewElement("host");
    host->SetText("ftp.some.url");
    subchild->InsertEndChild(host);

    XMLElement* port = xmlDoc.NewElement("port");
    port->SetText(21);
    subchild->InsertEndChild(port);

    XMLElement* protocol = xmlDoc.NewElement("Protocol");
    protocol->SetText(0);
    subchild->InsertEndChild(protocol);

    XMLElement* type = xmlDoc.NewElement("type");
    type->SetText(0);
    subchild->InsertEndChild(type);

    XMLElement* user = xmlDoc.NewElement("user");
    user->SetText("test");
    subchild->InsertEndChild(host);


    xmlDoc.SaveFile("SavedData.xml");

        cout << path << endl;
        std::wcout << username << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output file looks like this:

```
<FileZilla3 Version="" platform="">
    <Servers>
        <Server>
            <port>21</port>
            <Protocol>0</Protocol>
            <type>0</type>
            <host>ftp.some.url</host>
        </Server>
    </Servers>
</FileZilla3>
```

the desired uotput should be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FileZilla3 version="" platform="">
    <Servers>
        <Server>
            <Host>saddf</Host>
            <Port>21</Port>
            <Protocol>0</Protocol>
            <Type>0</Type>
            <User>username</User>
            <Pass encoding="base64" />
            <Logontype>1</Logontype>
            <PasvMode>MODE_DEFAULT</PasvMode>
            <EncodingType>Auto</EncodingType>
            <BypassProxy>0</BypassProxy>
            <Name>Ny tjener</Name>
            <SyncBrowsing>0</SyncBrowsing>
            <DirectoryComparison>0</DirectoryComparison>
        </Server>
    </Servers>
</FileZilla3>
```

Comment: I'm surprised this builds, as InsertEndChild does not take a pointer. Perhaps it didn't and you're using the last build version? You can also switch to LinkEndChild if you really want to use the pointers. Let me know if this helps and I'll write it up properly if so.

**[edit: turns out this is wrong and only applies to tinyxml, not tinyxml2]**

Answer (score 2):

```
XMLElement* user = xmlDoc.NewElement("user");
user->SetText("test");
subchild->InsertEndChild(host);
```

should be

```
XMLElement* user = xmlDoc.NewElement("user");
user->SetText("test");
subchild->InsertEndChild(user);
```